# How to wake up multiple threads using condition variable

Tags: c++, mutex, condition-variable

I want to run multiple threads every 100ms. In order to achieve that I thought of introducing `std::mutex` and `std::condition_variable`. The problem I'm facing is on what basis the threads should go into waiting state. This is my current code

```
std::mutex m;
std::condition_variable cv;
```

Timer_Thread.cpp

```
while (true) {
    std::lock_guard<std::mutex> LG(m);
    cv.notify_all(); // notifies every 100ms
}
```

Thread1.cpp

```
// multiple threads should run every 100ms
while (true) {
    std::unique_lock<std::mutex> UL(m);
    cv.wait(UL);
    UL.unlock();

    // do rest of the work
}
```

As you can see the threads are waiting without checking any predicate. Can somebody suggest any alternatives to achieve the same. All I want is to notify multiple threads every 100ms simultaneously.

Comment: If you don't want spurious wake-ups, you will need to add an extra flag to check as predicate for `wait`. What kind of alternative are you looking for? What is it about this approach that doesn't work for you?

Comment: @user17732522 like you said spurious wake-ups. Sometimes threads get run even before 100ms timeout.

Answer (score 0):

As you mentioned about spurious wake-ups, thus my solution is to use another variable flag to let the waked thread can distinguish the correct notified case and spurious waked up case. So actually, what comes to my mind is semaphore. The `counting_semaphore` needs c++20, but i think writing a similar naive semaphore in pre C++20 version by using `condition_variable` and `mutex` is not a hard thing to you.

```cpp
std::counting_semaphore<MAX_THREAD_NUM> semaphore;

// Timer_Thread.cpp
while (true) {
    semaphore.release(thread_num); // notifies every 100ms
}

// Thread1.cpp
// multiple threads should run every 100ms
while (true) {
    semaphore.acquire();
    // do rest of the work
}
```